# Mybatis scriptRunner could't rollback

Tags: java, mysql, mybatis

Use scriptrunner to run sql file, when error occurred, I want the sql could rollback,but it failed.
please help me..

Java code:

```
try {
    Class.forName(driver);
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);
    conn.setAutoCommit(false);
    ScriptRunner runner = new ScriptRunner(conn);
    runner.setAutoCommit(false);
    runner.setStopOnError(true);
    runner.setSendFullScript(false);
    runner.setDelimiter(";");
    runner.setFullLineDelimiter(false);
    runner.setLogWriter(null);

    Resource resource = new ClassPathResource(sqlFileName);
    File file = resource.getFile();
    runner.runScript(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

    conn.commit();
} catch (Exception e) {
    conn.rollback();
    error = e;
} finally {
    close(conn);
}
```

sql file:

```
create table daiql_test2 (
    id int,
    name varchar(100)
);

insert into daiql_test2 (id, name) value (1, 'test1');
update daiql_test2 set name = 'test2' where id = 1;

gold bless no bug...;
```

I use mysql database, and it don't work, so as oracle...
Not only DDL could not rollback , DML also can't rollback.
Is there some code errer here?

Mysql version:

```
select version();

5.7.20
```

Engine:

```
show table status where name= 'daiql_test2';

Name    Engine  Version Row_format  Rows    Avg_row_length  Data_length Max_data_length Index_length    Data_free   Auto_increment  Create_time Update_time 
daiql_test2 InnoDB  10  Dynamic 4   4096    16384   0   0   0       2019-11-19 15:56:47 2019-11-20 09:20:05     utf8_unicode_ci
```

Mybatis and Connection/J in pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.daiql</groupId>
    <artifactId>scriptrunner</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>scriptrunner</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>mysql</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>5.1.47</version>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->

        <!-- druid -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
            <artifactId>druid-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

application.yml:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: scriptrunner
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    url: jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/daiqltest?userUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF8&useSSL=false
    username: root
    password: abcdef
    druid:
      filters: stat
      max-active: 20
      initial-size: 5
      max-wait: 60000
      min-idle: 5
      time-between-eviction-runsMillis: 60000
      min-evictable-idle-timeMillis: 300000
      validation-query: select 'x' FROM DUAL
      test-while-idle: true
      test-on-borrow: false
      test-on-return: false
      pool-prepared-statements: true
      max-pool-prepared-statement-per-connection-size: 20
      connectionProperties: druid.stat.mergeSql=true;druid.stat.slowSqlMillis=5000
```

Comment: I couldn't reproduce it (i.e. the DDL is not rolled back, but the DMLs are rolled back by ScriptRunner). I tested with MySQL 5.7.15 with Connector/J 8.0.17. A few things to clarify: 1) Please add versions of MySQL, Connector/J and MyBatis to the question 2) Is there any connection property in the JDBC URL? 3) Execute this query `show table status where name= 'daiql_test2'` and verify the 'engine' is _not_ MyISAM.

Comment: @ave I post the info to the question. I usually used Mysql Connector/J 5.1.47,I changed it to 8.0.17,but still does't work....

Comment: The question looks perfect now.  I don't see any problem that could prevent the DMLs from being rolled back, though. Here is a portable [demo](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues/tree/so-58929535/so-58929535) that I used to verify the rollback. See if the test passes on your environment. It uses TestContainers which requires Docker installation to run fresh MySQL Server. If you don't have Docker environment, just rewrite the URL, etc. and be sure to delete the table before each run.

Comment: @ave  I push the code in [here](https://github.com/daiqingliang/script-runner) , you can try it. (ps: My java jdk version: 1.8.0_211). The code in my environment could not work correct. This confuse me ...

Comment: In the script (myTest.sql) of the demo project, there is no semicolon at the end of the  faulty line (unlike the snippet in this question). As a result, ScriptRunner does not execute that line and no exception is thrown. I just sent a PR, but if you add `;`, DMLs will be rolled back.

Comment: @ave Thank you.It really work when I add ```;``` to the end of sql file.